# WP_Http response throws "Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array"

Tags: plugins, http-api, wp-error

My plugin is throwing the error "Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array".  The line in question is...

```
$http = new WP_Http();
$response = $http->request( $url, array('timeout' => 20));

if( $response['response']['code'] != 200 ) { // THIS IS THE LINE
    return false;
}

$upload = wp_upload_bits( basename($url), null, $response['body'] );
```

So the problem is $response only has one result, so it's not an array?  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Your logic for your updated if statement is wrong.

`if( !is_wp_error($response) && $response['response']['code'] != 200 )`

Here you are saying; if NOT wp_error AND response code NOT 200 return false. So your not actually catching the WP_Error

I believe what you are after is something like:

`if ( is_wp_error($response) || $response['response']['code'] != 200 ) return false;`

IS wp_error OR code NOT 200

Comment: Thanks. Maybe figured it out by doing this:

`$http = new WP_Http();
$response = $http->request( $url, array('timeout' => 20));

$response = is_array($response) ? $response : array($response);

if( is_wp_error($response) && $response['response']['code'] != 200 ) {
    return false;
}`

But now I get the error: Undefined index: response

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think may have fixed it by doing this...

```
$http = new WP_Http();
$response = $http->request( $url, array('timeout' => 20));

$response = is_array($response) ? $response : array($response);

if( is_wp_error($response) && isset($response) && $response['response']['code'] != 200 ) {
    return false;
}
```